# Delete any non-word character but spaces and a single quote inside the word

Tags: regex, perl

Want cleanup some texts. So, want remove anything but `\w` and `\s`, but also want keep the single `'` inside the word. (e.g. want keep it in words like `don't`.

I could do

```
perl -plE "s/[^\w\s']//g" <<< "'a:b/c d????ef' don't"
```

which keeps the `'` but it keeps it also at the begining or end of string, e.g. it prints

```
'abc def' don't
```

I'm unable to implement the **keep this** `(?<\w)'(?=\w)`, e.g. remove the `'` unless it is between two word characters.

The wanted result:

```
abc def don't
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
s/[^\w\s']|(?<!\w)'|'(?!\w)//g
```

Delete everything that is either

- a character that is not (a word character or a space or `'`), or
- a `'` that is not preceded by a word character, or
- a `'` that is not followed by a word character

The first clause will match (and remove) all characters that we obviously don't want to keep.

The second and third clause will remove all `'` characters unless they're surrounded by word characters on both sides.

Comment: You should replace your lookarounds with `\B`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte True, that would have the same effect. It would probably take me a bit longer to read/understand, though,

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a global research instead of a replacement, this way you only have to describe what you want to keep and the pattern becomes more simple:

```
perl -ne"print /[\w\s]|\b'\b/g" <<< "'a:b/c d????ef' don't"
```

Comment: Wonderful! If I understand right, the `\b'\b` is the same as `(?<\w)'(?=\w)` but **much** simpler. :)

Comment: @Nemo: yes the idea is to find word characters, whitespaces and quotes surrounded by word boundaries instead of searching all other cases to replace them with nothing. Don't forget the `=` in your lookbehinds `(?<=...)`